# Disable suggested contacts in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook-2010

I need to disable the suggested contacts in outlook 2010 using a code that i can remote deploy to machines in the network.

Where/What is the setting to disable this feature?

EDIT: How do i do this through code? is there a registry setting that i can manipulate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook 2010 first go to File>options. Go to the Contacts tab and at the bottom disable 'Automatically create Outlook contacts for recipients that do not belong to an Outlook Address Book'.

Comment: How do i do this through code? is there a registry setting that i can manipulate?

Comment: Essentially it is at [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Preferences\] where the '11.0' can vary per user. For me it was 14.0. The variable is ShowAutoSug (0 for disable). Full Article: http://www.windowsreference.com/ms-office/how-to-enabledisable-autocomplete-in-ms-outlook/